# Need a simple Google Speech API example for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-speech-api

I need a simple Google Speech API example for .NET in which I upload a voice file and receive the text.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just worked for me, you can create a class as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
namespace GoogleAPI{

    public class GoogleSpeech
        {
            public string URL { get; set; }

            public void GetSpeechTranscript(string filePath)
            {
                try
                {

                    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    memoryStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
                    fileStream.Read(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

                    byte[] resBytes = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
                    HttpWebRequest request = null;
                    request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(this.URL + "&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
                    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=44100";
                    request.ContentLength = resBytes.Length;
                    Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                    stream.Write(resBytes, 0, resBytes.Length);
                    stream.Close();

                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        StreamReader reqStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                        var result = reqStream.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: This is the url for Google Speech API: https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE

Comment: Using this URL I'm getting The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: You can try with this url (+ key): https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?client=chromium&lang=en_US&key=AIzaSyAcalCzUvPmmJ7CZBFOEWx2Z1ZSn4Vs1gg

Comment: Still the same error using this URL. Does it work for you ?

Comment: Yes with my api key. I think you need to check your api key again. You can see error (400) when you type this url (https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?client=chromium&lang=en_US) on the browser. Also only 50 requests per day are provided for free.

Comment: Is it can be implemented in mobile platform like xamarin?